# tomcat webapp authentication

Tags: web-applications, authentication, tomcat

How do I add authentication for a particular webapp under tomcat home directory so that if someone tries to access via web browser, he should get a pop up username and password.

I understand that I will need to edit tomcat_users.xml and web.xml , but which web.xml exactly (under webapps/appname/WEB-INF or TOMCAT_HOME/conf)? and what content should the files have?

Answer (score 0):

To leverage the SSL protocol, the DD `web.xml` file should be modified so that the  tag contains a  tag indicating the security requirements.

```
<security-constraint>

<display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>

<web-resource-collection>

<web-resource-name>Secure Area</web-resource-name>

<url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>

<http-method>GET</http-method>

<http-method>POST</http-method>

</web-resource-collection>

<auth-constraint>

<role-name>manager</role-name>

<auth-constraint>

<user-data-constraint>

<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>

</user-data-constraint>

</security-constraint>
```

the  tag has two legal values, INTEGRAL and CONFIDENTIAL. The former requires that the data is guaranteed not to change in transit and the later requires that the data be guaranteed not to have been read by an unauthorized third party in transit. A CONFIDENTIAL guarantee implies INTEGRAL.

We also need to kick start form-based authentication, which requires the following configuration changes to the Web deployment plan.

```
<login-config>

<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>

<form-login-config>

<form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>

<form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>

</form-login-config>

</login-config>
```

or may be [this](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_admin.htm) link will help u